# Send all row in sql for print

Tags: c#, linq, stimulsoft

I apologize at the beginning because I am translating my question using google translator.
But my question is, I'm going to print a report using C # 2010 and Linq technology and StimulSoft Report software. My report is in the stimulsoft report environment in the New + Label Report. When the code that runs down is run, only the first person is selected from the database and the rest of the people are not added to the list. My question is how can I send all the people inside the bank for printing.

```
DBLinqDataContext db = new DBLinqDataContext();
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var SelectStudent = from row in db.InfoStudents
                       select row;
                StiReport report = new StiReport();
                report.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\\ReportPerson.mrt");
                report.Compile();
                report.RegBusinessObject("MyPerson", SelectStudent);
                report.Show();
        }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKQhD.jpg)

Comment: Try `report.RegBusinessObject("MyPerson", SelectStudent.ToList());`

Comment: Dear friend, I've tried this code before. But it was useless

Comment: AAA says right, otherwise chek report (`ReportPerson.mrt`) settings.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Dear friend. Which part of the settings should be checked?

Comment: Can you try with  var SelectStudent = from row in db.InfoStudents
                       select  new {row.colom_name,row.colom_name2,...}; like wise